# svn pre-commit hook fails all commits

Tags: svn, directory, hook

I need a way to stop the directory trunk from being deleted in svn. I decided to add pre-commit hook which should do this

Below is my pre-commit hook.

```
REPOS="$1"
SVNLOOK=/usr/bin/svnlook

$SVNLOOK changed "$REPOS" | grep '^D ' || exit 1 ;
exit 0
```

It seemed to work at first but now I cannot commit anything to svn with the hook.

I also tried to narrow it down so only if trunk is being deleted will it the commit failed

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $1 

REPOS="$1"
SVNLOOK=/usr/bin/svnlook

$SVNLOOK changed "$REPOS" | grep '^D.*trunk/$ ' || exit 1 ;
exit 0
```

But this also did not work. This hook is my preferred way  since users might want to delete something in trunk and this should pass the hook.

Any idea how I can get this working

Answer (score 0):

I did notice I had a || which caused my commits to fail. Below is my working solution.

REPOS="$1"
SVNLOOK=/usr/bin/svnlook

```
$SVNLOOK changed $REPOS | grep '^D.*trunk/$ '
if [ "$?" > "0" ];then
exit 1
fi
exit 0
```